# Should I store a large amount of pictures in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, size, apk

I am building an app in Android Studio and I have a problem. The basic idea of the app contains one Relative_layout with two buttons inside.Every time I press one button it sets the background of the layout to a Random image I have stored in the "res/drawable folder". The thing is that I am going to have a very big amount(larger than 10.000) of pictures(with high resolution) to be stored in that folder. Will this have a big effect on the APK size of the app? And if it does, is there any other more efficient way to store(or connect) a large amount of pictures with an android app?

Comment: Yes, it will. Load them over http.

Comment: Agree with the above. Use something like Picasso from square

Comment: Everything in the `res` folder will be packed with your apk, so the file size will grow with each picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

- Store the images as local resources, with very high res: Your application size will be huge
- Stroe the images as local resources, but with less resolution: Your application size will be smaller
- Store all the images on a web server, and retrieve them when you need it(Using picasso is super easy): Your application size will be very small.

You decide.

Answer (score 0):

if the number of images is large, it is better to store at server and load dynamically when required, use **Glide(fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework)**, you can load image and display with a single line of code.